# Replacing recursion with while loop (stair climbing puzzle): Python

Tags: python, fibonacci

I'm practicing replacing recursion with while loops, and I'm stuck on the following problem.

How many ways can you go up a staircase of length n if you can only take the stairs 1 or 2 at a time?

The recursive solution is pretty simple:

```
def stairs(n):
  if n <= 1:
    return 1
  else:
    return stairs(n-2) + stairs(n-1)
```

I feel like the structure for the iterative program should go something like this:

```
def stairs_iterative(n):
  ways = 0
  while n > 1:
    # do something
    ways +=1
  return ways
```

But I don't know what I need to put in the #do something part.  Can someone help me?  Pseudocode is fine!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This amounts to the top-down (recursive) approach vs. the bottom-up (iterative) approach for dynamic programming.

Since you know that for input `n` you need all values of `stairs(p)` for `0 <= p <= n`. You can iteratively compute `stairs(p)` starting at `p = 0` until you reach `p = n`, as follows:

```
def stairs(n):
    table = [1, 1]  # p = 0 and p = 1
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        table.append(table[i - 2] + table[i - 1])
    return table[n]
```

Comment: BTW for this simple task you only have to store 2 previous values, not the whole table.

Comment: @monkeybiz7 It's fibonacci with an offset.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach than @univerio is to use a list as stack:

```
def stairs_it(n):
    res = 0
    stack = [n]
    while len(stack) > 0:
        curr = stack[0]
        stack.remove(curr)
        if curr == 0:
            res += 0
        elif curr == 1:
            res += 1
        elif curr == 2:
            res += 2
        else:
            stack.append(curr-1)
            stack.append(curr-2)
    return res
```

Comment: OK, you're gonna have to explain this.  I'm not seeing how it does what the original does.

Comment: @cHao it sounds a bit like an order rather than a request :) I'll come back after I tuck the kids into bed and add explanation, though I thought that this approach will be more 'intuitive' than the memoization above

Comment: I'm figuring out how it works.  You're basically doing "data recursion", and using the stack to store the data rather than passing it to yourself.  It takes a bit of time to reason about, though.  (BTW, the original returns 1 when `n` is 0.)

Comment: @cHao yeps, you got it! One could argue if n=0 should return 1 or zero, but either way it's easy to add a condition at the beginning of the function.