# Algorithm for a stair climbing permutation

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I've been asked to build an algorithm that involves a permutation and I'm a little stumped and looking for a starting place. The details are this...

You are climbing a staircase of *n* stairs. Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps at a time. How many distinct ways can you climb to the top?

Any suggestions how I can tackle this challenge?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing recursion with while loop (stair climbing puzzle): Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517791/replacing-recursion-with-while-loop-stair-climbing-puzzle-python)

Comment: Why the upvotes? This is clearly a question without any research effort, and far too broad for SO.

Comment: Lack of research and general nature of question is outweighed by importance of question to CS and how annoying a problem it is

Answer (score 7):

You're wrong about permutations. Permutations involve orderings of a set. This problem is something else.

Problems involving simple decisions that produce another instance of the same problem are often solvable by dynamic programming. This is such a problem.

When you have n steps to climb, you can choose a hop of either 1 or 2 steps, then solve the smaller problems for n-1 and n-2 steps respectively. In this case you want to add the numbers of possibilities.  (Many DPs are to find minimums or maximums instead, so this is a bit unusual.)

The "base cases" are when you have either 0 or 1 step. There's exactly 1 way to traverse each of these.

With all that in mind, we can write this dynamic program for the number of ways to climb n steps as a recursive expression:

```
W(n) = W(n - 1) + W(n - 2)  if n > 1
       1                    n == 0, 1
```

Now you don't want to implement this as a simple recursive function. It will take time exponential in n to compute because each call to W calls itself twice. Yet most of those calls are unnecessary repeats. What to do?

One way to get the job done is find a way to compute the W(i) values in sequence. For a 1-valued DP it's usually quite simple, and so it is here:

```
W(0) = 1
W(1) = 1  (from the base case)
W(2) = W(1) + W(0) = 1 + 1 = 2
W(3) = W(2) + W(1) = 2 + 1 = 3
```

You get the idea.  This is a very simple DP indeed. To compute W(i), we need only two previous values, W(i-1) and W(i-2).  A simple O(n) loop will do the trick.

As a sanity check, look at W(3)=3.  Indeed, to go up 3 steps, we can take hops of 1 then 2, 2 then 1, or three hops of 1. That's 3 ways!

Can't resist one more? W(4)=2+3=5. The hop sequences are (2,2), (2,1,1), (1,2,1), (1,1,2), and (1,1,1,1): 5 ways.

In fact, the chart above will look familiar to many. The number of ways to climb n steps is the (n+1)th Fibonacci number. You should code the loop yourself. If stuck, you can look up any of the hundreds of posted examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void printPath(int n,String path) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(path.substring(1));
    }
    if (n-1 >=0) {
        printPath(n-1,path + ",1");
    }

    if (n-2 >=0) {
        printPath(n-2,path + ",2");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        printPath(4,"");
    }
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd point out that this code is in C#. There are lots of people who don't know C# syntax and standard library.

Answer (score -1):

Since it looks like a programming assignment, I will give you the steps to get you started instead of giving the actual code:

- You can write a recursive function which keeps track of the step you are on.
- If you have reached step n then you found one permutation or if you are past n then you should discard it.
- At every step you can call the function by incrementing the steps by `1` and `2`
- The function will return the number of permutations possible once finished

Comment: This solution will use quite a lot of space and can cause [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) if *n* is big enough. However I can easily see an algorithm with a constant memory footprint here (unless I misunderstood the question). Did you intentionally provide an inefficient solution so [SeanT](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1026755/seant) can find a more optimal way to do his on?